# My code shows error inflating class fragment, for recycler view. This is my code, Adapter class, and all the xml files I used

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio, android-recyclerview, material-design

I was searching similar questions, and found that people either did not write the compile dependency for Recycler View, or they did not mention the right id in their code, as used in the xml, or they returned null in the onCreateViewHolder. I made sure to not repeat those mistakes, but the app still crashes. Can someone help me, I'm very new to Android development.

Adaptor class:

```
package com.example.sayan.materialtoolbar;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by SAYAN on 21-02-2016.
 */
public class AppAdaptor extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AppAdaptor.myViewHolder> {
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    List<Information> data= Collections.emptyList();

    public AppAdaptor(Context context, List<Information> data){
        inflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.data=data;
    }
    @Override
    public myViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, parent,false);
        myViewHolder holder=new myViewHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(myViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Information current=data.get(position);
        holder.title.setText(current.title);
        holder.icon.setImageResource(current.iconId);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    class myViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView title;
        ImageView icon;
        public myViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            title= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.listText);
            icon= (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.listIcon);

        }
    }
}
```

Class for storing the data:

```
package com.example.sayan.materialtoolbar;

/**
 * Created by SAYAN on 21-02-2016.
 */
public class Information {
    int iconId;
    String title;
}
```

The Navigation Drawer Fragment

```
package com.example.sayan.materialtoolbar;


import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class NavigationDrawerFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String PREF_FILE_NAME ="testpref" ;
    private static final String KEY_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER ="user_learned_drawer" ;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private boolean mUserLearned;
    private boolean mFromSavedInstanceState;
    private View containerView;

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private AppAdaptor adaptor;

    public NavigationDrawerFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        readFromPreferences(getActivity(), KEY_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, "false");
        mUserLearned=Boolean.valueOf(readFromPreferences(getActivity(), KEY_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, "false"));
        if(savedInstanceState!=null)
            mFromSavedInstanceState=true;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View layout=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
        recyclerView= (RecyclerView) layout.findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        adaptor=new AppAdaptor(getActivity(),getData());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adaptor);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        return layout;
    }


    public void setUp(int fragmnentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout, final Toolbar toolbar) {
        containerView=getActivity().findViewById(fragmnentId);
        mDrawerLayout=drawerLayout;
        mDrawerToggle=new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(),drawerLayout,toolbar,R.string.drawer_open,R.string.drawer_close){
            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                if(mFromSavedInstanceState){
                    mUserLearned=true;
                    saveToPreferences(getActivity(),KEY_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER,mUserLearned+"");
                }
                getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        if(!mUserLearned && !mFromSavedInstanceState)
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(containerView);
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mDrawerToggle.syncState();
            }
        });
    }
    public void saveToPreferences(Context context, String preferenceName, String preferenceValue){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(preferenceName, preferenceValue);
        editor.apply();
    }
    public static String readFromPreferences(Context context, String preferenceName, String defaultValue){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return sharedPreferences.getString(preferenceName,defaultValue);
    }
    public static List<Information> getData(){
        List<Information> data=new ArrayList<>();
        int[] icons={R.drawable.ic_book_black_36dp,R.drawable.ic_book_black_36dp,R.drawable.ic_book_black_36dp,R.drawable.ic_book_black_36dp};
        String[] titles={"Academic Details","Live Shows","Recorded Songs","Paper publications"};
        for(int i=0; i<icons.length && i<titles.length; i++)
        {
            Information current=new Information();
            current.iconId=icons[i];
            current.title=titles[i];
            data.add(current);
        }
        return data;
    }
}
```

custom_row xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="@dimen/icon_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/list_height"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_book_black_36dp"
        android:id="@+id/listIcon"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/list_height"
        android:text="Dummy text"
        android:id="@+id/listText"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Error logcat

```
02-22 11:35:19.908  21466-21466/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.sayan.materialtoolbar, PID: 21466
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sayan.materialtoolbar/com.example.sayan.materialtoolbar.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22: Binary XML file line #22: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2426)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22: Binary XML file line #22: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
            at com.example.sayan.materialtoolbar.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6245)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:782)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
            at com.example.sayan.materialtoolbar.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6245)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setAdapter(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter)' on a null object reference
            at com.example.sayan.materialtoolbar.NavigationDrawerFragment.onCreateView(NavigationDrawerFragment.java:57)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1036)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1226)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1328)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2284)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:111)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:314)
            at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:31)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:79)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:754)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
            at com.example.sayan.materialtoolbar.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6245)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

Comment: you have posted everything except that class which has error

Comment: possible error in this line  recyclerView= (RecyclerView) layout.findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout); , is your recyclerview id really drawer_layout

Comment: I called the wrong recycler view id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U have a wrong id specified to recyclerview :

Change

```
recyclerView= (RecyclerView) layout.findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
```

to

```
   recyclerView= (RecyclerView) layout.findViewById(R.id.your_recyclerview_id);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I called the wrong recycler view id